# Mongoose post hook Type error in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using mongoose and typescript, when I call updateOne() on the model I want to use

```js
someSchema.post<Query>('updateOne', function(doc: IsomeDoc) {
    console.log(this)
}
```

The problem is that `this` is of type Query if I suppress typescript checker and ignore  as it give me an error:

`Generic type 'Query<ResultType, DocType, THelpers>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.`

This is my schema

```js
const someSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _id: { type: String, required: true },
    status: { type: String },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)
```

How can I get the correct type for `this` inside the function? After lots of searching there is barely any use of post hook with typescript and mongoose.
What is ResultType?

**Edit:**

After seeing @gregooroo's answer I was able to get past Query by making it `Query<IsomeDoc, IsomeDoc>` but it does not give me the correct type for this object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For query middlewares you need to construct a Query type with a generic type of what this query should return

```js
someSchema.post<Query<IsomeDoc, IsomeDoc>>('updateOne', function(doc) {
    console.log(this)
}
```

Comment: while it stops giving me errors, when I type `this._update` the compiler saids it does not exist but if I use @ts-ignore it does print out a property

Comment: Oh I see. So apparently "_update" is not exposed in Mongoose type. I found this snippet on the internet: https://pastebin.com/HUgUq0Ka Maybe it will help you @F22lightning

Comment: There is zero documentation on this or on using typescript with mongoose in general, thank you!

Comment: That's true. Especially now (mongoose >5.11) when they are working on their own TypeScript definitions, so couple of things may work different.